# Implement synchronous code in IActionResult.ExecuteResultAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I don't know if someone can help me understand this better.

I'm writing a class that implements `IActionResult`. This requires that my class implements the following method.

```
Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context);
```

In my case, the implementation of this method needs to write XML, using `XmlWriter` to `context.HttpContext.Response.Body`.

The problem is that I don't think I need to run asynchronously here. (I don't know if `context.HttpContext.Response.Body` is just a memory stream. If so, I definitely see no reason to run asynchronously.)

So my options are:

1. Use the asynchronous versions of the XML methods.

   - This seems unnecessary and like it could actually hurt performance with all the unneeded `await`s.
   - For some reason the asynchronous methods have completely different arguments, and I'm not even sure what they are.
2. Use something like `Task.RunSynchronously()`.

   - Does this have performance ramifications?
   - Do I need special handling for any exceptions?

Comment: Thanks for the edit (I can't seem to ping you under the answer for some reason), but have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7644), particularly reading from [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7644#issuecomment-493626822) down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionResult` is abstract, but defines `public virtual void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)` that you could override, in addition to inheriting from `IActionResult`.

Also note that `ActionResult` implements `IActionResult`. And the [source code for `ActionResult`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ActionResult.cs,5c2548bb3f42589d) is online so you can even see how `ActionResult` dealt with this issue by creating a synchronous method that implements `IActionResult.ExecuteResult()`.

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, writing XML using `XmlWriter` to `context.HttpContext.Response.Body` causes an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.'

This remains a problem.